# Access Accounts settings on Mac OS X from terminal

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

Is there any way to access Account settings from terminal? By Account settings I mean default Account page in System preferences with informations about Automatic login etc. I need to save this setting to a file for later reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate a bunch of things in `System Preferences` with AppleScript, see some examples here: 
http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html

Comment: THX. I'm a bit lost in it. Don't you know how to get to the "Login Options" in "Accounts" pane in "System Preferences"? Only thing I found is getting properties of the security preferences, but not all needed info is there, e.g. "Network Account Server".

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Open the preference pane at that location? Programatically view them without a GUI?  Programatically add to them for the current user without a GUI?